# Проблема с лайфтаймом параметров замыкания. "returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`"

Tags: rust

Я пытаюсь сделать вывод треков в очереди музыкального бота с использованием библиотек Serenity и Songbird.

```rust
async fn queue(ctx:&Context, msg:&Message) -> CommandResult{
    let guild = msg.guild(&ctx.cache).unwrap();
    let guild_id = guild.id;
    let manager = songbird::get(&ctx).await.unwrap();
    if let Some(handle_lock) = manager.get(guild_id) {
        let handle = handle_lock.lock().await;
        let queue = handle.queue();
        let embed_func  = |e:&mut CreateEmbed| -> &mut CreateEmbed {
            e.title("Очередь треков");
            if let Some(t) = queue.current() {
                e.field("Сейчас играет:", t.metadata().title.clone().unwrap(), false);
            }
            queue.modify_queue(|queue| {
                for i in 0..queue.len() {
                    if let Some(t) = queue.get(i) {
                        e.field(format!("#{} Трек", i), t.metadata().title.clone().unwrap(), false);
                    }else {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
            e
        };
        let _ = msg.channel_id.send_message(&ctx.http,   |m| {
            m.embed(embed_func)
        }).await;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Я вынес замыкание дабы захватить внешнюю переменную queue в которой хранится список треков в виде структуры TrackQueue. Просто проставить статические лайвтаймы в аргументе замыкания и результата нельзя так как будут отличатся сигнатуры. Метод .embed требует `FnOnce(&mut CreateEmbed) -> &mut CreateEmbed`

Ошибка возникающая из-за лайвтаймов:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
|
318 |         let embed_func  = |e:&mut CreateEmbed| -> &mut CreateEmbed {
    |                              -                    - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'2`
    |                              |
    |                              let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
332 |             e
    |             ^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

Comment: А метод .embed не может вернуть этот &mut CreateEmbed ?

Answer (score 0):

Изначальной проблемой(как оказалось несуществующей) была невозможность использование в лямбде внешней переменной. Как оказалось моя IDE просто неправильно мне подсказывала сигнатуру переменной. Решением оказалось простой перенос замыкания внутрь метода .embed().

**Решение: замена замыкания на лямбду**

```rust
async fn queue(ctx:&Context, msg:&Message) -> CommandResult{
    let guild = msg.guild(&ctx.cache).unwrap();
    let guild_id = guild.id;
    let manager = songbird::get(&ctx).await.unwrap();
    if let Some(handle_lock) = manager.get(guild_id) {
        let handle = handle_lock.lock().await;
        let queue = handle.queue();
        let _ = msg.channel_id.send_message(&ctx.http,   |m| {
            m.embed(|e| {
                e.title("Очередь треков");
                if let Some(t) = queue.current() {
                    e.field("Сейчас играет:", t.metadata().title.clone().unwrap(), false);
                }
                queue.modify_queue(|queue| {
                    for i in 0..queue.len() {
                        if let Some(t) = queue.get(i) {
                            e.field(format!("#{} Трек", i), t.metadata().title.clone().unwrap(), false);
                        }else {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                });
                e
            })
        }).await;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```